# printing user of subshell obtaining root via su -

Tags: linux, debian, bash, shell, bashrc

Can I print the username which is obtaining root access via `su -` on the root console upon obtaining root?

```
user1$ su -
password:

obtained root via user1
#
```

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4598001/how-do-you-find-the-original-user-through-multiple-sudo-and-su-commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Previously I recommend the script below...
I found a better way! :) Just exec:

```
logname
```

Also, you can use `$SUDO_USER`, but doesn't work if you are using `sudo su -` 
By the way, `who am i` is like `who -m`

This script also does the work:

```
#!/bin/bash
curpid=`awk '/^PPid:/{print $2}' /proc/$BASHPID/status`
ppui=`awk '/^PPid:/{print $2}' /proc/$curpid/status`
ppui=`awk '/^PPid:/{print $2}' /proc/$ppui/status`
uid=`awk '/^Uid:/{print $2}' /proc/$ppui/status`
name=`cat /etc/passwd | grep $uid | awk -F: '{print $1}'`
echo $name
```

Call it through `.bash_profile` if you are using login shells or `.bashrc` if using interactive non-login shells.

Comment: Great idea using `logname`. Sometimes it's difficult to see the simplest solution ;).

Answer (score 1):

`who am i|awk '{print "Obtained root via "$1}'`

Add it to root's `.bashrc` to execute when you `su`.

You can also try

`pstree -p -u |grep "$$"`

to see the whole chain of processes with usernames. This could be useful if you have nested `su` with multiple users.

Comment: do you mean 'who | awk ..."

Comment: No, I mean exectly what I wrote. `who | awk` will not work, because it will display all users that are logged in. Invoking who with two parameters is a nice trick, which displays only information about user who owns your terminal (so the one you `su`-ed from).

Comment: Anyway, using logname, as suggested in another comment, seems to be the simplest solution.

Comment: `who am i`  does not do anything on my debian system

Comment: It works in OSX and Centos Linux. Maybe `who -m` works for you ?

Comment: `who -m` also leads to nothing `who` just gives me a single line with my user `who -a` gives me all users logged in ...

Comment: Ok, so Debian's who is a little different then. Use `man who` on your system as a definitive guide :).

Comment: I am going with logname since that gives me the session username which is what I want! Thanks for your kind help!